# Translating merge in Pandas into a join in PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, pyspark

I have two dataframes of the same shape, each with 3 columns, I want to see if for every pair `col_1, col_2`, the value in the benchmark is equal to the value in the second dataframe, and output the problematic rows:

```
input_benchmark =

col_1    col_2   col_to_check
girl     12      Primary
boy      14      Secondary
baby     1       Nursery
girl_1   10      Secondary
girl_2   10      Secondary

input_df =

col_1    col_2   col_to_check
girl     12      Primary
boy      14      Secondary
baby     1       Secondary
toddler  3       Kindergarten
girl_1   10      null
girl_2   10      null
```

My code works:

```
def check_func(input_benchmark, input_df):
    df_new = input_df.merge(input_benchmark, on=['col_1', 'col_2'], suffixes=(None, '_actual')).query('col_to_check != col_to_check_actual')
    return df_new

col_1    col_2   col_to_check   col_to_check_actual
baby     1       Secondary      Nursery
girl_1   10      null           Secondary
girl_2   10      null           Secondary
```

Is it possible to do this in Spark? I haven't found anything similar to the `query` function that I used.

Answer (score 0):

In spark your `query` would really be a `filter`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df1 = (
    spark
    .createDataFrame([
        ('girl', 12, 'Primary'),
        ('boy', 14, 'Secondary'),
        ('baby', 1, 'Nursery')], 
        ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_to_check']
    )
)

df2 = (
    spark
    .createDataFrame([
        ('girl', 12, 'Primary'),
        ('boy', 14, 'Secondary'),
        ('baby', 1, 'Secondary'),
        ('toddler', 3, 'Kindergarten')],
        ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_to_check'])
    .select(
        'col_1',
        'col_2',
        col('col_to_check').alias('to_check') # alias this column so it isn't ambiguous
    )
)

df3 = (
    df1
    .join(df2, on=['col_1', 'col_2'])
    .filter('col_to_check != to_check')
)

df3.show()

+-----+-----+------------+---------+
|col_1|col_2|col_to_check| to_check|
+-----+-----+------------+---------+
| baby|    1|     Nursery|Secondary|
+-----+-----+------------+---------+
```

## Edit

To handle `NULL` values, you'll want to use `coalesce` with a default return value of some sort:

```py
df3 = (
    df1
    .join(df2, on=['col_1', 'col_2'])
    .filter('coalesce(col_to_check, "default") != coalesce(to_check, "default")')
)

df3.show()
+------+-----+------------+---------+
| col_1|col_2|col_to_check| to_check|
+------+-----+------------+---------+
|  baby|    1|     Nursery|Secondary|
|girl_1|   10|   Secondary|     null|
|girl_2|   10|   Secondary|     null|
+------+-----+------------+---------+
```

Comment: I tried it out on my data and I get an empty dataset. In my original data, the input_df has empty rows on the column I have to check and that's where the Pandas solution detects them. But with the PySpark solution nothing comes out.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show those specific cases?

Comment: @johnnydoe I've added a new edit, I think this should address your problem